# JSESSIONID conflicting with two webservers on the same root domain

Tags: jboss, jsessionid

i´d like to ask for heads up.

**The situation:**
I have 2 applications running on 2 JBosses. The first app runs at www.domain.com. The second runs at secondapp.domain.com.

**The problem:**
Once I visit www.domain.com, I get JSESSIONID cookie for domain ".domain.com". Then, When I go to the second app, and I login, I get another JSESSIONID for domain ".secondapp.domain.com".

The problem is the authentication. When I login at the first app and then go to the second app and log in there, I get unauthorized in certain steps (in steps that check that you are logged in). My thought is that the problem might be in 2 JSESSIONIDs conflicting with each other (something like for the secondapp.domain.com the browser sends both JSESSIONID cookies, because they both matches the domain mask with root .domain.com. And for some reason, the cookie for domain.com is resolved wrongly as first).

Do you see any solution for this?

I´m a noob here, but can the secondapp.domain.com first check cookies it gets and than according to the cookie domain choose the proper one? Or can I throw away cookies according to their domain even on jboss level?

Thank you for any proposal how to solve this! I´d take any idea :-)

Comment: What version of the servlet API are you on?  If you're on Servlet API 3.0, check out the session-config property of the web.xml.

Comment: What does that mean? You propose changing the name of the cookie?